# reducing php memory usage for image resizing

Tags: php, image, memory, memory-management, resize

I'm currently creating a PHP website where users need to be able to upload images, which then need to resized down to a reasonable size. My php configuration is set to a memory limit of 50mb.

The problem is when uploading images over around 5mb, php is not able to resize the image(due to to much memory use). So I was wondering if there's anyway to optimize memory usage of a resizing images. Here's what I currently use:

```
class Image {


  var $uploaddir;
  var $quality = 80;
  var $ext;
  var $dst_r;
  var $img_r;
  var $img_w;
  var $img_h;
  var $output;
  var $data;
  var $datathumb;

  function setFile($src = null) {
   $this->ext = strtoupper(pathinfo($src, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
   if(is_file($src) && ($this->ext == "JPG" OR $this->ext == "JPEG")) {
    $this->img_r = ImageCreateFromJPEG($src);
   } elseif(is_file($src) && $this->ext == "PNG") {
    $this->img_r = ImageCreateFromPNG($src);      
   } elseif(is_file($src) && $this->ext == "GIF") {
    $this->img_r = ImageCreateFromGIF($src);
   }
   $this->img_w = imagesx($this->img_r);
   $this->img_h = imagesy($this->img_r);
  }

  function resize($largestSide = 100) {
    $width = imagesx($this->img_r);
    $height = imagesy($this->img_r);
    $newWidth = 0;
    $newHeight = 0;

    if($width > $height){
      $newWidth = $largestSide;
      $newHeight = $height * ($newWidth / $width);
    }else{
      $newHeight = $largestSide;
      $newWidth = $width * ($newHeight / $height);
    }

   $this->dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor($newWidth, $newHeight);
   imagecopyresampled($this->dst_r, $this->img_r, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
   $this->img_r = $this->dst_r;
   $this->img_h = $newHeight;
   $this->img_w = $newWidth;
  }

  function createFile($output_filename = null) {
   if($this->ext == "JPG" OR $this->ext == "JPEG" OR $this->ext == "PNG" OR $this->ext == "GIF") {
    imageJPEG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'."jpg", $this->quality);
   } /*elseif($this->ext == "PNG") {
    imagePNG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext);
   } elseif($this->ext == "GIF") {
    imageGIF($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext);
   }*/
   $this->output = $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext;
  }

  function setUploadDir($dirname) {
   $this->uploaddir = $dirname;
  }

  function flush() {
   $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
   $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
   $targetFile = str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

   imagedestroy($this->dst_r);
   unlink($targetFile);
   imagedestroy($this->img_r);

  }
```

And then for resizing I do:

```
  $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
  $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
  $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

  move_uploaded_file ($tempFile, $targetFile);

  $image = new Image();
  $image->setFile($targetFile);
  $image->setUploadDir($targetPath);
  $image->resize(200);
  $image->createFile(md5($id));
  $image->flush();
```

I'm current using uploadify, but it uses this upload / resize script. Is there anyway to optimize this code so that it uses less memory?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a 5000 x 5000 pixel image would be 16.7 inches at 300DPI and that would come in at 5.2  Mb. you may want to set some reasonal expectation on image sizes, say about 10 megapixels?

a 14 megapixel image measures 4672 x 3104 and as a JPEG would fit well within a 5 Mb image size restriction.

also look and see if there is enough memory savings by using a palleted method such as imagecreate as opposed to imagecreatetruecolor.

there is also some help already on the php site for determining your memory requirements based on image size [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php#99623)

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was not the actual file size, but the file resolution that was the problem. I've used the link you provided to make validation. Thanks a lot. I've also used .htaccess to increase memory limit as I couldn't event upload images at 2848 x 4288 (12mp) which I guess it quite normal for a image with a camera.

Comment: Please explain your numbers... When glib uses these images does it not need to decompress to bitmap? If so, a 5000x5000 image would be 5000x5000x3(24 bits), or ~71 meg... Wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The pragmatic thing to do would be to just call an external program, e.g. ImageMagick to do the resizing.

Comment: If you're looking to reduce memory usage, ImageMagick isn't the best bet.  It tends to run wild with memory and disk usage.  While it won't cause the php script to die due to memory limits, it could potentially consume all the memory on the server, creating yet more issues.

Comment: Don't have imagemagick installed on my host, probably for that reason :)

Comment: CItation Needed. That's hasn't been my experience at all, and I'm routinely resizing 3000x3000+ jpegs on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that opening the file up with `imagecreatefromjpeg` uses a lot less memory than opening the first into a string (`file_get_contents`)- and then using `imagecreatefromstring`?

Also, I would limit file uploads to 2-4MB. There is no reason for people to waste your bandwidth sending huge files.

Comment: @Craige did I say that he did? Why the downvote for sharing something that most people don't know?

Comment: It was certainly implied by your answer. He asked how to optimize HIS code, and you answered with a statement that had nothing to do with the code he posted (referring to your first statement). The implication was also extended by your use of the word 'Also' beginning your second statement. This was a poor answer at best, even if you didn't directly say he uses file_get_contents.

Comment: @Craige, you are correct and your analysis valid. Still, I do believe some grace could have been shown since the effort to share information was put forth (despite the deficiency of the communication). ;)

Comment: I do appreciate the extra knowledge, but I suggest labeling these under a heading of "General Tips", or something similar. Separating these from the direct answer to the posed question is key. In a Q+A site, communication/understanding is important.