# Is there a way to reduce php createimagefromjpeg memory usage?

Tags: php, image-uploading, large-files, memory-limit

I'm building a website where I should be able to upload really large images (from 2MB to 50MB). Of course I need to resize them, but [createimagefromjpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) function uses A LOT of memory. Memory usage hits 800 megabytes for some of the images, but I'm using hostgator's shared plan and 256M memory is maximum there. Can I somehow reduce the memory this function uses?

Comment: If you're worried about efficiency, you should break this command out to a binary (ImageMagick is what I use for CLI scaling in Linux)

Comment: @Dave is that possible on hostgator shared plan?

Comment: You can't reduce `createimagefromjpeg`'s memory usage, it does what it does. You'd have to read the image into memory little by little while resizing it. I have no idea whether there's a library out there that does this or whether it's really possible to resize an image without loading it into memory at once.

Comment: @vazha.asatiani According to the post at http://forums.hostgator.com/would-like-see-imagemagick-installed-t57.html?s=c85eeaedd5d8cd75dd5ce5a3783dafa7&amp ImageMagick should be installed on your server. I'll write an answer on how to use

Comment: thanks @Dave! it's installed. I'll find out how to use it since I've never used it. So it shouldn't be a problem for the php memory_limit right?

Comment: Please contact hostgator for technical support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Hostgator forums](http://forums.hostgator.com/would-like-see-imagemagick-installed-t57.html?s=c85eeaedd5d8cd75dd5ce5a3783dafa7&) ImageMagick should be installed on your server. I would recommend using a binary for something such as image resizing because of sheer efficiency. To do what you are looking to do, a command such as this will suffice (assuming you want the 2 MB you asked for):

```
$SCALED_VALUE = (2097152/filesize($OLD_IMAGE))*100; #< Get the percentage of scaling that is required to go to 2MB
shell_exec('convert '. $OLD_IMAGE . '-resize ' . $SCALED_VALUE . '% new_image.jpg'); #< Perform scaling
```

To answer the question regarding php_memory_limit in the comments; this limit is within PHP and will not affect ImageMagick (or any other application other than PHP).

Comment: Thanks very much, Dave. After all these hours, there is finally a hope.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching to a different image manipulation library like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or [Gmagick](https://www.php.net/GMagick) instead of relying on the GD extension. You will have to install these dependencies and restart Apache.

If this is not possible, think about reducing the pixel size of your images as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4619441/427992).